# How to speed up the Firebase authentication process

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have an Android app with Firebase-backed storage. For authentication, I'm using a Google sign-in, followed by Firebase's `signInWithCredential()`.

This is sometimes reasonably fast, some other times very slow (2 seconds for the Google sign-in, 6 seconds for Firebase, sometimes longer). This is not acceptable from a UX point of view, especially since this happens every single time the user starts the app.

Is there anything I can do to speed things up?

In a nutshell, with all async handling removed:

```
result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(googleApiClient).get();
// --- That can take over two seconds ---

GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
authTask = auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
// --- This can take over six seconds ---
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Authentication time depends on Network speed and Firebase Servers.

There is no need to login the user every time they launch your application because

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()
```

**will not be null unless you explicitly sign out** the user with

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
```

In case you want to update the Auth instance for newer changes you can call `reload` on profile which will be faster than re-login.

**Why you might need to reload the profile?**

Let's say the user was logged in and you blocked that account from Firebase Dashboard. In this case, user will still be logged in. You can `reload` the profile instead of re-login to revoke user access.

Comment: Wow, the solution is so blindingly obvious that I feel legitimately stupid! I never considered for a second that the FirebaseAuth would retain its state after a restart. In hindsight, it makes perfect sense since Firebase leaves files in the data directory for each app instance. Congrats on your first accepted answer :)