# Firebase not loading data and getting stack in loading when sign in and signing up

Tags: android

I've noticed that Firebase authentication has been extremely slow on Android only. When I try to login using the auth ui interface, I get stuck on the loading screen for around 5-10 minutes. This happens for both login and sign up.

Comment: what is the question? and if you will share some code it would be easier to help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69357147/why-firebase-authentication-is-slow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878734/how-to-speed-up-the-firebase-authentication-process

Comment: bro can you share the code? How to understand without sharing code